# Not able to get the metadata of the component through java Broker API code

Tags: 2011, java, 2011-sp1

I am trying to get the metadata of the component published to broker.
Here is the code snippet -

Note :-  in docIds[i] i have the component Ids.

```
ComponentPresentationFactory compfac = new ComponentPresentationFactory(pubId);
ComponentMetaFactory compmf = new ComponentMetaFactory(pubId);

for (int i =0; i < docIds.length; i++)
{
  ComponentPresentation cp = cpf.getComponentPresentation(docIds[i], "tcm:189-2786-32");    
  ComponentMeta meta = cmf.getMeta(docIds[i]);
  CustomMeta custom = meta.getCustomMeta();
  Map<String, NameValuePair> map = custom.getNameValues();
 NameValuePair pair = map.get("date");
 String value = (String) pair.getFirstValue(); }
```

I am not able to get the value of "date" metadata field of the components .Could somebody help me here.

Is my approach is correct or i have to go some other way around.

Comment: What do you mean by *I am not able to get the metadata*? What is wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: Hi Ant,I am not sure what is wrong, but i am not getting anything. R u saying that the code is correct and it should work.

Comment: Where do you declare `cmf`, which doesn't seem to match the `ComponentMetaFactory compmf`.? In terms of the methods, I understand we have `.getMeta()` but .getCustomMeta() and `.getNameValues()` aren't familiar. There *are* properties called `.CustomMeta()` and `.NameValues()`, though. See a Bart Koopman's example in this answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2783/46. Maybe you have the wrong object?

Comment: The methods in the code are correct, the examples @AlvinReyes refers to are .NET, not Java. His point about the cmf / compmf confusion is correct, but I guess those are copy/paste errors?

Comment: The first place to check is in the Broker database and to see whether the CUSTOM_META table is filled correctly. I wonder for instance whether a field name called 'date' is actually inputted in the right way and whether the date is actually set correctly. If the correct values are present, check the values of the Map<String,NameValuePair> with a debugger. Pay special attention to the actual Type for each map entry and value.

Comment: Thanks, @Quirijn. Oops, yes I was specifically looking at the .NET CD API docs (out of habit, really).

Comment: Thanks Guys for help. I did a very very stupid typo mistake which Alvin and  Quirijn mentioned above.